# Paypal Express Checkout Recuring with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I'm looking to do recuring billing with Paypal and Rails 3. I like the process with Express Checkout, where the customer goes to paypal to enter details, but confirms on my website.

I've looked into ActiveMerchant, however their support for Recuring billing with Paypal Express Checkout isn't there.

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that there is a patch for ActiveMerchant, which is good enough.

Comment: Was the "patch" in the latest gem?  or was it a hack?  Got a link?

Comment: I believe that this fork should do the trick: https://github.com/rayvinly/active_merchant/